# How to achieve this kind of color texture in illustrator or photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, texture

[image]

I want to achieve this sandstone like color texture but have no clue how to achieve it as i'm new to illustrator. Any clue how to achieve this color texture?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Gabriel Yakub. Can you tell something more about your efforts? Have you performed some internet search or tried to generate some noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In photoshop there's a filter called Reticulation that can easily achieve this. It's under Stylize and if you're on CC you first have to go into the Filter Gallery to get to it, in older versions it would just be on the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or adding a noise in photoshop Filter->Noise->Add Noise

Comment: Your answer is right, but... upload an image to to make it more clear. @Sam-Sepiol .